# What are the classifiers that can be used for sequence data?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naive-bayes, sequence-analysis

I've been going through the classifiers like Naive Bayes, Decision Tree etc. I've a sequence data like so

```
[1,2,3,6,4,5] = Class A
[1,2,3,5,4,6] = Class B
[1,2,6]       = Class C
```

Can anyone help me out with a generic classifier that I can choose for such data?

Comment: You could look at RNNs, HMMs or sequential pattern mining with classification